# Freeing a struct which has a function pointer causes SIGTRAP

Tags: c, struct

Messing around with some structs with function pointers (first time using) and running into SIGTRAP.

I've stepped through it and the problem seems to be with the function pointer in the struct, the code works fine, output is as expected, however, SIGTRAP thrown when trying to free the structs.

If I however comment out the line:

```
short int (*SampleColour)(const struct sSprite* s, short int nSampleX, short int nSampleY);
```

(and all the other necessary lines following) The free works fine and no error thrown!

Here it is:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>



typedef struct sSprite{
    short int nHeight;
    short int nWidth;
    short int* nColourArray;

   short int (*SampleColour)(const struct sSprite* s, short int nSampleX, short int nSampleY);
}sSprite;


short int SampleColour(const struct sSprite* s, short int nSampleX, short int nSampleY){
    return *(s->nColourArray + nSampleY*s->nWidth + nSampleX);
}

sSprite* spriteFireBall;
sSprite* spriteBlob;

typedef struct sObject{
    float x;
    float y;
    struct sSprite* sprite;
}sObject;

short int yellow = 0x0000;
short int green = 0x00001;
int main(){

    spriteFireBall = (sSprite*) malloc(sizeof(sSprite*));
    spriteBlob = (sSprite*) malloc(sizeof(sSprite*));

    short int* nColourFireBall = (short int*) malloc(16*sizeof(short int));
    short int* nColourBlob = (short int*) malloc(16*sizeof(short int));

    for(short int i = 0; i < 16; i++){ //inti the sprite colours
        *(nColourFireBall + i) = yellow;
        *(nColourBlob + i) = green;
    }

    spriteFireBall->nHeight = (short int) 4;
    spriteFireBall->nWidth = (short int) 4;
    spriteFireBall->nColourArray = nColourFireBall;
    spriteFireBall->SampleColour = SampleColour;

    spriteBlob->nHeight = (short int) 4;
    spriteBlob->nWidth = (short int) 4;
    spriteBlob->nColourArray = nColourBlob;
    spriteBlob->SampleColour = SampleColour;

sObject listObjects[3] ={{8.5f, 8.5f, spriteBlob},
                        {8.5f, 6.5f, spriteFireBall},
                        {8.5f, 7.5f, spriteFireBall}
                        };      


        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            sObject object = listObjects[i];
            printf("objectId: %d\n", i);
            for(int j = 0; j < object.sprite->nWidth; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < object.sprite->nHeight; k++){
                   printf("colour: %d. j=%d, k=%d\n", object.sprite->SampleColour( object.sprite, (short int) j, (short int) k), j, k);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        printf("going to free now!");
        free(nColourFireBall);
        free(nColourBlob);
        free(spriteFireBall); //<---- Exception thrown here
        free(spriteBlob);
        return 0;
}
```

Should I leave this up? 
And yes, I know I shouldn't be casting malloc but old habits die hard. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: "Should I leave this up?" Yes. You should never remove a question just because it got a simple answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
    spriteFireBall = (sSprite*) malloc(sizeof(sSprite*));
    spriteBlob = (sSprite*) malloc(sizeof(sSprite*));
```

Those should instead be this:

```
    spriteFireBall = (sSprite*) malloc(sizeof(sSprite));
    spriteBlob = (sSprite*) malloc(sizeof(sSprite));
```

You were only allocating enough space to hold a pointer, not to hold the structure. Then when you used it, it was Undefined Behavior, which means literally anything can happen, and in this case, "anything" meant "crash when you call free() on something with a function pointer inside".